# Referring Askers to other SE sites?

Tags: support

Are there any rules on referring Askers to other SE sites where their question might be equally or more appropriate?

I've done so in comments several times.  Sometimes the comment stays, other times not.

I'd like to understand the rules on this.

Comment: In general, you don't unless the question is completely and unsalvageably off-topic here.

Comment: This question has also been [discussed on Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258172/what-is-the-etiquette-about-recommending-sites-in-comments/258178).

Comment: @EmC Thanks!  But oh boy, that opens a can of worms.  My deleted comment actually fully satisfies 1-3, 4 being not relevant since the Q is OT for both.  Should I re-add the Comment?

Comment: @EmC To be clear, I did describe The Workplace topics but can just as easily link to their guidance/description.

Comment: No, it would be deleted again. My intent was only to provide some additional context for readers who wanted to know how the rest of the network handles it. See Monica's comment under the top answer: "It's bad form to suggest "it would be better on site B" *if it is on-topic on Site A*."

Answer (score 8):

From

> comments here are strictly for asking for clarifications or suggesting improvements only

I'd say there are two types of situations.

### 1. Question is off topic for IPS

It would then either get closed or edited to be on topic eventually (sometimes both). If it can't be edited in such a way that it would be on topic for IPS AND you're certain that **it'd be on topic on another SE site** then yes, you should leave a comment suggesting the question should be migrated.

### 2. Question is on topic for IPS

If it was originally posted on IPS one can assume **the asker is looking for interpersonal advice** so the question is perfectly valid. Then I'd say you shouldn't suggest migration/cross posting because 1. we can assume the asker originally looked for IPS advice and 2. such comments don't fit the site policy. One more important point: it may be understood as *"this isn't a good question for IPS, please ask it somewhere else"*.

I know sometimes there are questions you might think would be a great fit on another site as well. But we must respect the asker's will and assume they came to the right place. There are more than enough regular IPS users to know most of the existing SE sites and to indicate them if there's a better (SE) site to turn to.

Comment: I think this really should be opened up.  SE is a very big place and "respect the asker's will and assume" is just a presumptions as assuming they took the time to review all, what, 100+ sites to find the best fit.  Can you clarify this: "We're more than enough to indicate them if there's a better (SE) site to turn to."  Who can indicate there's a better site?

Comment: @Johns-305 the community.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Well, that's why I'm asking.  I recommend a work related question also be asked in The Workplace and the comment was deleted.  Who is the 'we' in avazula's statement?

Comment: @Johns-305 I edited my answer to address your question.

Comment: @Johns-305 your comment was deleted because you answered the question on IPS, and it's about etiquette which is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: If it's on-topic here you shouldn't move it to The Workplace and the comment was deleted because it doesn't provide improvement to the question.

Comment: Be in mind that comments are temporary so there is no need to explain why a comment was deleted (in general).